# Need to subtract values from Column G to Column H, when Column J is clicked & store it in Cell M3 through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Need to subtract values from Column G to Column H (G-H) when Column J is clicked & Store it in specific cell M3 through VBA, this will happen for the entire range i.e G4:G76, H4:H76 & J4:J76

if only J4 cell is clicked it will subtract (G4-H4), if J5 cell is clicked it will subtract (G5-H5), if J6 cell is clicked it will subtract (G6-H6) and store & overide values in M3 depending which row was clicked so on and so forth

I tried below code, this macro can be called when any cell in column J is clicked however this displays it in the entire column M. I dont need that, only when respective cell in J column is clicked it should display the calculation in only cell M3.

```
Sub FormulasNoLoops()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Range("M4:M" & LastRow) = Evaluate("G4:G" & LastRow & "-H4:H" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Macro Calling Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4")) Is Nothing Then
            Call FormulasNoLoops
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you should rewrite `FormulaNoLoops` to accept a `Range` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Columns("M").value = .Columns("G").Value - .Columns("H").Value
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```